# OpenCV MedianBlur function crashing when Mat is of type CV_32S

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, filtering

I am working on Demosaicing a Bayer pattern to RGB image without using OpenCV's direct conversion function. I have used Bilinear interpolation and got it to work, but I want to improve the quality by using The Freeman Method. This method requires Median Filter. OpenCV has medianBlur function which does that. But I am having trouble using this function. When the cv::Mat to which I apply medianBlur is of type CV_8UC1 then it works, but if it is of type CV_32S, then it does not work.
This does **NOT** work:

```
    redGreenMedian.create(input.size(), CV_32S);
    blueGreenMedian.create(input.size(), CV_32S);
    blueMinusGreen.create(input.size(), CV_32S);
    redMinusGreen.create(input.size(), CV_32S);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i += 2)
    {
            cv::medianBlur(redMinusGreen, redGreenMedian, i);
            cv::medianBlur(blueMinusGreen, blueGreenMedian, i);
    }
```

If I change all CV_32S to CV_8UC1 then it works. On debugging I found that it crashes in the second iteration only not in first one. However, I need it to run for both iterations. This does **NOT** work when written separately too:

```
    cv::medianBlur(redMinusGreen, redGreenMedian, 3);
```

As an aside, I do not have to use CV_32S, but I need the ability to store negative numbers in the matrices.
**NOTE**: I have tried making all numbers in the matrices positive and then use medianBlur, but it still did not work.
All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yup, segfault for not handling the input is not usual! I have only seen crashes because of `medianBlur` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=medianblur#medianblur) seems to be very clear:

> **src** – input 1-, 3-, or 4-channel image; when `ksize` is 3 or 5, the image depth should be `CV_8U`, `CV_16U`, or `CV_32F`, for larger aperture sizes, it can only be `CV_8U`.

As you need to cater for signed values, I think your best option is to use `CV_32F`.

Also, the documentation says

> **ksize** – aperture linear size; it must be odd and greater than 1, for example: 3, 5, 7

Your loop applies sizes of 1 and 3 (if I read your code correctly), the first of which is invalid, which possibly explains why your first iteration doesn't crash (because it fails earlier).

Comment: Thanks. CV_32F works. I was starting the iteration from 1 because I was following the example given in: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html